# Scrolling to a specific position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a map for the game I run, the map is already [quite big](http://woarl.com/map/turn_26_normal.html) and I'd like to make it possible to scroll to a position with Javascript. I have jQuery in use should that be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, if you goto woarl.com/map and look at the older ones you can see that it's improved somewhat with time (and help from here)

Comment: You could add a marker and then scroll to the dom element using Element.scrollIntoView()

Answer (score 1):

You can move to specific positions by using jQueries `scrollTop()` and `scrollLeft()` functions. See documentation:

https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

https://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/

Put a call in your `$(document).ready()` to jump to specified position like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").scrollLeft(2000);
    $("body").scrollTop(800);
});
```

This question is very old, I recognized it, but I was curious :) Maybe it helps someone.